# multiple directives on 1 element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

Given that I have the following two directives.

1: Angular UI select - this directive uses isolate scope.

2: myDirective - in my custom directive i also use isolate scope to access the value of ngModel

I am getting the Multiple directive error cannot share isolate scope. This is how I declare the isolate scope in my directive.

```
 require: 'ngModel',           
            scope: {
                modelValue: "=ngModel"
            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
```

And i use it like:

```
<ui-select myDirective  multiple ng-model="GroupsModel" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;" hidden-text-box ">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="groups">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="color in Groups ">
            {{color}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

My question is, how I can get access to the ngmodel value from my custom directive if multiple directives cannot be used together on 1 element, is there a work around that will still keep the binding ?

**Updated**

I cannot access the required ng models value in the following function of my directive if I don't use empty the `scope: {},`

```
scope.reset = function () {

                            var modelValue =ctrl.$viewValue;

                            $timeout(function () {
                                el[0].focus();
                            }, 0, false);
                        };
```

Here is my directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.directive('resetField', [
        '$compile', '$timeout', '$http', function ($compile, $timeout, $http) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',                                
                link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {

                    // compiled reset icon template
                    var template = $compile('<i ng-show="enabled" ng-mousedown="reset()" class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="padding-left:5px"></i>')(scope);
                    el.after(template);

                    scope.reset = function () {

                        var modelValue =ctrl.$viewValue;

                        $timeout(function () {
                            el[0].focus();
                        }, 0, false);
                    };

                    el.bind('input', function() {
                            scope.enabled = !ctrl.$isEmpty(el.val());
                        })
                        .bind('focus', function() {
                            scope.enabled = !ctrl.$isEmpty(el.val());
                            scope.$apply();
                        })
                        .bind('blur', function() {
                            scope.enabled = false;
                            scope.$apply();
                        });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using isolated scope only to get the ng-model for the select, you can do it without using isolated scope.

In the link function just use `scope[attrs.ngModel]`, you can even put a watch over it (as long as the ngmodel is a object property `ng-model=obj.prop1`)

Comment: I have updated my question with my directive can you have a look please

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple directives on one element, the issue is that applying multiple isolated scopes on one element is invalid, you can use [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to require another directive in `myDirective`:

```
angular.directive('myDirective', [function(){

    return {
        scope: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){

            scope.modelValue = ctrl.$viewValue;

        }
    }

}])
```

Comment: Sorry there is another case that I didn't mention. MyDirective sometimes is used without multiple directives. given this, will your solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'require' in the directive to be able to access the controller of another directive.  Then you are able to inject that controller in the params of the directives implementation.  However, you cannot use an isolate scope if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

if there are two directives that you need to use, make sure that the second directive is not an isolated one.

Comment: But sometime, I need to use myDirective without another directive. How can i access ngmodel value without isolation scope in this case?

Comment: The scope that you will be using will be of the controller that element is in. You can modify the variables in the respective contollers

Comment: I have updated my question with my directive can you have a look please

Comment: if you use a normal directive and not an isolated one, you have access to the scope of controller that directive is in, hence you dont need to define a scope. the scope of this directive is that of the controller of the view where the directive is used. You have access to GroupsModel directly